# Is there any way to change my realm of magic?

Tags: spells, fighter, rolemaster, middle-earth-role-playing

I am currently participating in a MERP campaign in which I play a 3rd level fighter.When I generated said Fighter I researched spellcasting. Fighters can only learn very low level spells and have to work hard to invest points into learning spell lists. After reading through the rules and consulting with my party ( which includes an NPC essence-user and a PC Ranger) I decided that investing in skill lists was probably not something I would be doing at any point during my campaign. However my GM said that I needed to at least choose a realm even if I was not planning on using it. On a whim I chose Essence and forgot about it for several months.

Fast forward 8 months into our campaign.

Over the past few weeks it has rapidly become apparent that my GM wants me to move into the use of channeling magic in order to further my role in the story. He has made this clear through hints both in and out of story and has also been feeding me very powerful items useful to channeling spell casting. The obvious problem here is that I chose Essence at character generation. I asked if I could be allowed to change my chosen realm from Essence to Channeling, due to the fact that it had literally never come up in game and that I was given no indication at character creation that I would ever have to be involved in magic. He said no. ( which I grudgingly: I made the character I have to live with it). However, he did propose an alternative: If I could figure out some way to change my realm in game he would allow me to change my character's chosen realm of magic. This brings me to my question. Are there any ways either through the rules of MERP or the lore of Middle Earth to change my realm of magic.( This question also applies to Rolemaster Players as my GM would likely accept a solution from Rolemaster)

Comment: I dont really know how to tag this correctly or whether it is a valid question in the first place so any feedback either on the question or answering it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The question reads fine to me and I do not think it needs anything either removed or added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of the time when a GM says “figure out some way to *X* in-game”, they're suggesting that you *figure it out* in-game, not figure it out *out-of-game* and just do the final step in-game. **This is an adventure hook.** To follow the hook means getting your character to investigate and do research in-game.

So get thee to a sage! I'm sure they'll have interesting things to say about these powerful items and how you might learn to unleash their awesome power.

Comment: You were exactly right. I have identified the sage, it remains to be seen if he actually tells me what i need to know or if i can even get to him.